# Objective-C .h file not working

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C or just the C language by itself for that matter so excuse my ignorance if this question is super easy or obvious. For some reason the contents of my .h file is not working with my main.m

If I place this code at the top of my main.m the program compiles fine:

```
@interface Person : NSObject{
NSString *_firstName;
NSString *_lastName;
int _age;
}

- (NSString *) firstname;
- (void) setFirstName: (NSString *) newFirstName andLastName:(NSString *)newLastName;

@end
```

however the same code in my person.h file gives me the following error: Use of undeclared identifier Person.

Here is the code for all my files.

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


//@interface Person : NSObject{
//    NSString *_firstName;
//    NSString *_lastName;
//    int _age;
//}
//
//- (NSString *) firstname;
//- (void) setFirstName: (NSString *) newFirstName andLastName:(NSString *)newLastName;
//
//@end

//NSString *firstName = @"Thomas";
//NSString *lastName = @"Eggenberger";
//int age = 29;



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

        [person setFirstName:@"Thomas" andLastName:@"Eggenberger"];


    //        NSLog(@"Hello there, %@ %@, you are %d years old",firstName, lastName, age);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject{
    NSString *_firstName;
    NSString *_lastName;
    int _age;
}

- (NSString *) firstname;
- (void) setFirstName: (NSString *) newFirstName andLastName:(NSString *)newLastName;
@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (NSString *) firstname {
    return _firstName;
}

- (void) setFirstName:(NSString *)newFirstName andLastName:(NSString *)newLastName{
    _firstName = newFirstName;
    _lastName = newLastName;
}

@end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Looks to me like you're not importing the .h file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top of your main.m file you need to import the Person class header, just like you do in the Person.m file. This gives it visibility of the definition.

```
#import "Person.h"
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. I knew I was missing something obvious. Cheers!